# Use content of a tuple as variable session

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I extracted from a previous response an Object of tuple with the following regex :

```
.check(regex(""""idSc":(.{1,8}),"pasTemps":."codePasTemps":(.),"""").ofType[(String,String)].findAll.saveAs ("OBJECTS1"))
```

So I get my object :

```
OBJECTS1 -> List((1657751,2), (1658105,2), (4557378,2), (1657750,1), (916,1), (917,2), (1658068,1), (1658069,2), (4557379,2), (1658082,1), (4557367,1), (4557368,1), (1660865,2), (1660866,2), (1658122,1), (921,1), (922,2), (923,2), (1660875,1), (1660876,2), (1660877,2), (1658300,1), (1658301,1), (1658302,1), (1658309,1), (1658310,1), (2996562,1), (4638455,1))
```

After that I did a Foreach and need to extract every couple to add them in next requests  So we tried :

```
.foreach("${OBJECTS1}", "couple") {        

                              exec(http("request_foreach47"
                                             .get("/ctr/web/api/seriegraph/bydates/${couple(0)}/${couple(1)}/1552863600000/1554191743799")
                                            .headers(headers_27))
                              }
```

But I get the message : named 'couple' does not support index access

I also though that to use 2 regex on the couple to extract both part could work but I haven't found any way to use a regex on a session variable. (Even if its not needed for this case but possible im really interessed to learn how as it could be usefull)

If would be really thankfull if you could provided me help. (Im using Gatling 2 but can,'t use a more recent version as its for work and others scripts have been develloped with Gatling2)

Answer (score 0):

each "couple" is a scala tuple which can't be indexed into like a collection. Fortunately the gatling EL has a function that handles tuples.

so instead of

```
.get("/ctr/web/api/seriegraph/bydates/${couple(0)}/${couple(1)}/1552863600000/1554191743799")
```

you can use

```
.get("/ctr/web/api/seriegraph/bydates/${couple._1}/${couple._2}/1552863600000/1554191743799")
```